# Call oracle method add_months using CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I've a query that I would like to execute using `CriteriaQuery`.

**Query:**

```
select * from MY_TABLE where updated_at <= add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 1, -3)
```

It is basically finding all records in table whose `update_at` date is earlier than 3 months.

I tried the approach presented at [this blog](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-call-custom-function-criteriaquery/).

Issue is I've `-3` as the parameter, but my expected return type is `Date`.

**Code:**

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> root = cq.from(MyTable.class);
Expression<Date> truncExpr = cb.function("TRUNC", Date.class, cb.currentTimestamp());
Expression<Date> addMonthsExpr = cb.function("add_months", Date.class, truncExpr, months); // <----Compilation error.
Predicate datePredicate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("updated_at"), addMonthsExpr);
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `months` variable is not displayed, but my guess is that it is an integer, e.g.:

```
int months = -3; // or from a method argument of type int anyway
```

The correct way is the following (unintuitive unless you know about it):

```
Expression<Integer> months = cb.literal(-3);
```